# Node JS mysql looping query push to array

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm having some trouble with below code. Can someone please take a look and advise what's going on?

```
const name = ["a", "b", "c"]

  let query1 = ('SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = ? AND status IN ("Pending","Active") limit 1')
  if (name instanceof Array) {

    async function getNames() {

      try {
        name.forEach(async (name) => {
          let newName = []
          let rows = await promisePool.query(query1, name);

          if (rows[0].length > 0) {
            if (rows[0])
              newName.push(rows[0][0].uid_name)
              console.log(newName)
          }
          return (rows);

        })
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log('ERROR => ' + err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    await getNames();

console.log(newName) returns (if row is found) 
['a']
['b']
```

how can I push any returning value to the array ? `desired output ['a','b']` so I can compare it to the original array.

Thanks in advance,
Ucin

I have changed the code a bit but to be honest I'm still not that of an expert.

```
const name = ["a","b","c"]
let query1 = ('SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = ? AND status IN ("Pending","Active") limit 1')
 
  if (name instanceof Array) {

    async function getNames() {
      
      try {
       for(names of name) {
         
          let rows = await promisePool.query(query1,[uid,challenge_type,names]);
  
        
            return (rows);
          
        }
        }
     catch (err) {
      console.log('ERROR => ' + err);
      return err;
  }
    }
  
  let newVar = await getNames();
    console.log(newVar[0])
```

the newVar only returns 1 line, where there should be 2 names.

```
name.forEach(async (element) => {
         
          let rows = await promisePool.query(query1,[uid,challenge_type,element]);
  
          if (rows[0].length > 0) {
            if (rows[0])
           /*  newName.push(rows[0][0].uid_name) */
            console.log(rows[0])
            
               
      return (rows);
```

if I go with `forEach...Of`, I can console.log it within scope, but return(rows) is undefined

Comment: don't fully get your target but....1) are you certain you want to use `.forEach` for async and not `for … of`? significant diff. for async/await 2) you are creating `newName` in each loop, resetting it with each cycle, is that intended, also you never return it and use `rows` in the end...

Comment: thanks, the target is to run the query for each of the items in the name array, and check if the row exists. If it does, it will return the same name. Then add those to a new array so that I can compare the newNames array with the original name array and do something with the missing name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are looping through the names and executing a query per name? If all you want to do is see which of those names in the array already exist in your database you could do it all in a single query. Something like:

```js
const names = ["a","b","c"];
const query = 'SELECT name FROM table WHERE name IN (?) AND status IN ("Pending","Active")';
const result = await promisePool.query(query, [names]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's always good to get a second opinion! I was struggling with this and after a while seems like I lost focus :)  You were right on spot , I was unnecessarily looping through the name array. everything works as expected. I can now get the diff between original and query returned values and finally move on with it. Thanks much